# Error in plotting and solving equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am trying to find the roots of this expression and plot the first two:

```
0.005*(-13 + P)*sqrt (x) - (14.53 + 2*x)*(0.01*sqrt (x) + 85.23*x) == 
  0 // Solve[#, x] &
```

This says Mathematica file is "running" for a while...

Comment: `Sqrt[ x]` and what is the `P`.

Comment: x is a function of P, so I am trying to plot x vs P

Comment: `ContourPlot` is ok.

Comment: Well trying to find real roots using reduce is not working ``Reduce[0.005*(-13 + P)*
     sqrt[x] - (14.53 + 2*x)*(0.01*sqrt[x] + 85.23*x) == 0 , x, 
  Reals]`` this gives error:``Reduce::ivar: -(105580102787/21792458700)+2.55757*10^11/(1.17692*10^33+2.29479*10^45 sqrt^2)^(1/3)+(1.17692*10^33+2.29479*10^45 sqrt^2)^(1/3)/43584917400 is not a valid variable.``

Comment: In Wolfram, this expression returns something different:
``Solve[0.005*(-13 + P)*     sqrt[x] - (14.53 + 2*x)*(0.01*sqrt[x] + 85.23*x) == 0 ]``

Comment: Sqrt, not sqrt. All built-ins are capitalized. You should also Quit[] to get a fresh kernel, you may have old definitions that get in the way.

Comment: Thanks, yes I had to do Quit. If I want to plot one specific root like the second one how can I do that?

Comment: Not sure how to use Contourplot since roots are complicated here

Comment: Is x always real and greater than zero? Is so there is a root at x=0 but not elsewhere. It is easy to plot P as a function of x where this is clearly seen. If you are looking at complex roots then we need to know that.

Comment: You should ask a new question instead of edit the original question since the original question have been solved completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `FindInstance`+ `ListPlot`.

We can use  `FindInstance` to search some solutions.

```
sol = {P, x} /. 
   FindInstance[{ 
     0.005*(-13 + P)*
        Sqrt[x] - (14.53 + 2*x)*(0.01*Sqrt[x] + 85.23*x) == 0, 
     x > 0}, {P, x}, Reals, 100];
ListPlot[sol]
```

[image]

- `ContourPlot`.

```
ContourPlot[
 0.005*(-13 + P)*Sqrt[x] - (14.53 + 2*x)*(0.01*Sqrt[x] + 85.23*x) == 
  0, {P, -100, 10000}, {x, 0, .0015}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Blue, 15], Style["P", Blue, 15]}]
```

[image]

- `Solve`+ `Plot`.

```
sol = SolveValues[
   Rationalize[
    0.005*(-13 + P)*Sqrt[x] - (14.53 + 2*x)*(0.01*Sqrt[x] + 85.23*x) ==
      0, 0], x, Reals];
Plot[sol, {P, -100, 1000}]
```

[image]